# Value of required=false custom attribute in tag file if not set?

Tags: jsp, tags, jstl

I have the following attribute defined in my .tag file:

```
<%@ attribute name="cssFiles" required="false" type="java.lang.String" description="comma delimited list of .css files to link" %>
```

And then further down it is used like so:

```
<c:forEach items="${fn:split(cssFiles,',')}" var="cssFilename">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/${cssFilename}.css" />
</c:forEach>
```

Whenever the attribute is not set when I call this tag, I see in the html this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/.css">
```

Is the attribute set to null or a blank string?  In either case, is there a jstl function to do hasText()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${!empty cssFiles}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

You should use [`<c:forTokens>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forTokens.html) instead of `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: This worked, but I'd like to add that doing fn:trim(cssFiles) could be a more robust solution.